# Is my following table in 3NF. How do I maintain 3NF even when I have repetition as follows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, normalization

This is how I have structured my tables. The tables are AGENT, OFFICE, TRAINING respectively. Same as the question line, is the following table in 3NF? Is it bad practice to have 2 FK?

Things are fine when we assume each office only has one agent or that each agent only has one training. When I look into offices having more than 1 agent and agents having more than 1 training, it becomes messy and no longer 3NF. The first set of table are with no repetitions. The second set displays the repetitions. Please advice. Thanks.

No repetition:

[image: 1]

Same tables but information repetition:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to find out if my tables are in 3NF and how I could overcome the issue when I have multiple Agents for the same office. I honestly don't see how this is going to be answered based on opinions.  IF that is the case, it works the same for any question where there is likely more than one answer and different people are going to have different 'opinion' on how it should be answered. Please unfreeze the question. In need for some answers. Would appreciate it.

Comment: 1) Identify the entities 2) Identify the relationships between the entities 3) Determine the cardinality of each relationship (e.g. one-to-zero_or_one, one-to-many, many-to-many, etc.) in each direction of the relationship. That will reveal which side of the relationship should get a foreign key, or whether an additional table should be added to resolve a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: sorry about your question getting closed. While there is some room for opinion on an answer, the question is really answered by applying Entity Relationship Modeling; determining the cardinalities on the relationships. For example, if an `office` can have more than one agent, but an agent can be related to at most one office, then the foreign key would be an `office_id` column on the `agent` table. If an agent can be related to more than one office, and and office can have more than one agent, then add a third table `agent_office` that has two foreign keys, office_id and agent_id...

Comment: Can I get an idea on how this agent_office works. Just 2 FKs and no PK?

Comment: Based on the data in your second example, to get a 3NF implementation, there's really no opinion involved. You'd need to remove all the foreign keys from those tables, and add two new tables: `"agent_office(agent_id FK, office_id FK, PRIMARY KEY (agent_id, office_id)"` and `"agent_training (agent_id FK, training_id FK, PRIMARY KEY (agent_id, training_id)"`. Adding a row to `agent_office` establishes the relationship between one `agent` and one `office`. The relationship itself can also have attributes (i.e. additional columns) for example, `date_assigned` when an agent was assigned to an offic

Comment: I am not able to understand the PK. for agent_office, the FKs are fine. But the Pk is the same. So it is just a repeition? For example: 1001, 3001, 1001, 3001 (PK,PK,FK,FK)?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY would be a composite key, composed of both columns. `CREATE TABLE agent_office (agent_id INT NOT NULL, office_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (agent_id, office_id), CONSTRAINT FK_agent_office_agent FOREIGN KEY (agent_id) REFERENCES agent (id), CONSTRAINT FK_agent_office_office FOREIGN KEY (office_id) REFERENCES office (id))`. That's the traditional 3NF table we'd created to resolve a many-to-many relationship. (In some edge cases, there may not be a unique constraint on the `(agent_id,office_id)` tuple, notably when there is temporal data.)

Comment: I wish I could have given you a formatted answer. Developing a 3NF model isn't "opinion" based at all. Where the opinion comes in is in whether implementing a pure 3NF model is the most suitable approach for an application. 3NF may just be a stepping stone. Denormalizing (introducing managed redundancy) may provide a performance benefit over a purely 3NF model. But it's an important stepping stone, getting a 3NF model that "works" conceptually is important first step, before denormalizing.

Comment: Agent(_Id_, Name); Office(_Id_, Name); Training(_Id_, Name); AgentTrainingOffice(_AgentId_, _TrainingId_, _OfficeId_) could be an option?

Comment: @RubensFarias To check, for AgentTrainingOffice, all 3 attributes are FK with no Pk?

Comment: @spencer7593 seems the hold on the question is lifted :)

Comment: @kesh_k, those FK will also be marked as PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easiest way to get to 3NF is by applying Entity Relationship Modeling methodology

1. Identify the entities
2. Identify the relationships between the entities
3. Determine the cardinality of each relationship (e.g. one-to-zero_or_one, one-to-many, many-to-many, etc.) in each direction of the relationship.

The cardinality of each relationship will reveal which side of the relationship should get a foreign key, or whether an additional table should be added to resolve a many-to-many relationship.

For example, if an office can have more than one agent, but an agent can be related to at most one office, then the foreign key would be an office_id column on the agent table. If an agent can be related to more than one office, and and office can have more than one agent, then add a third table **`agent_office`** which has two foreign keys, **`office_id`** and **`agent_id`** each referencing one of the related tables (**`office`** and **`agent`**, respectively.)

Assuming:

Entities:

- office
- agent
- training

Relationships:

- an agent can be related to zero, one or more offices
- an office can be related to zero, one or more agents
- an agent can be related to zero, one or more training
- a training can be related to zero, one or more agent

---

```
CREATE TABLE office
( id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
, ...
)

CREATE TABLE agent
( id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
, ...
)

CREATE TABLE training
( id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
, ...
)
```

To resolve the many-to-many relationship between agent and office:

```
 CREATE TABLE agent_office
 ( agent_id INT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'composite PK, FK ref agent.id'
 , office_id INT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'composite PK, FK ref office.id'
 , PRIMARY KEY (agent_id, office_id)
 , CONSTRAINT FK_agent_office_agent FOREIGN KEY (agent_id) REFERENCES agent (id)
 , CONSTRAINT FK_agent_office_office FOREIGN KEY (office_id) REFERENCES office (id)
 )
```

Similarly for the many-to-many relationship between agent and training, we add another table:

```
 CREATE TABLE agent_training
 ( agent_id INT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'composite PK, FK ref agent.id'
 , training_id INT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'composite PK, FK ref training.id'
 , PRIMARY KEY (agent_id, training_id)
 , CONSTRAINT FK_agent_training_agent FOREIGN KEY (agent_id) REFERENCES agent (id)
 , CONSTRAINT FK_agent_training_training FOREIGN KEY (training_id) REFERENCES training (id)
 )
```

---

In some edge cases, there may not be a unique constraint on the (agent_id,office_id) tuple, especially when we consider retaining temporal data. (For example, if we need to track that agent 99 was assigned to Office 7 from 2009 thru 2011, and was again assigned to Office 7 starting in 2013.) But if all that we need our model to answer is whether an agent is "assigned" to a particular office or not, then we can have a unique constraint on the (agent_id, office_id) tuple.

In terms of "training", is that a particular training course (e.g. "Sensitivity"), and what if agent 86 repeatedly attends the same "training". Then likely we would have a "training_session" table, related to a "training course", but offered at a particular time and location. Then we'd probably instead have a relationship "agent *attended* training_session".

---

Anyways, this Entity Relationship Modeling methodology is the quickest way to get to a 3NF model.

The opinion comes in on whether implementing a purely 3NF model is the most appropriate for a particular application. Denormalizing the model from 3NF, that is, introducing controlled redundancy, effectively "breaks" 3NF, and is quite suitable for some applications, primarily because it provides some performance benefits, and can make some code simpler.

The key here is that we are AWARE of the redundancy, that the database implementation is NOT 3NF, and the application implements logic that controls/manages the redundancy.